# How to make npm request work with Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a dataservice and I'd like to use external npm [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package, cos I have some problems with Angular $http

```
(function () {
        angular.module('app').factory('dataservices', dataservices);

        /* @ngInject */
        function dataservices($state, $rootScope, authService) {
            var request = require('request'); // This does not work

var getData = () => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                request({
                    url: 'url',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'token'
                    }
                }, (error, response, body) => {
                    if (error) {
                        return reject(error);
                    }
                    return resolve(response);
                });
            });
            }
      }
```

The question is how to use npm request in my dataService??

Comment: The `request` module isn't designed to be used in the browser - see https://github.com/request/request/issues/2090.

Comment: "I have some problems with Angular $http"  **What problems**, exactly?  That would be a better question that might get a useful answer.

Comment: Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344077/how-to-get-status-code-in-angular-1-5-6

Comment: that question has a pretty clear answer;  They show that you can get the error status in the `.catch` block.  You made some comment about not using `$httpbackend`, but `$httpbackend` isn't needed, it was used by the person answering the question so that they could demonstrate it works without having to make an API of their own.  you can still use the `.catch(error)` in your code without issue.

Comment: in other words, `$http` works just fine, and the `ng-request` that was recommended in an answer here is just a wrapper around `$http`, it would give the same results.

Comment: I've tried to put catch everywhere and still the same result http://prntscr.com/evjq86

Comment: can we have a skype call, my skype is medvedevdenis12

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think that `npm request` will work with `angular`.

It's use to make `REST` call from `back-end`(Node.js)

You can use [ng-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-request) instead

Comment: Just inject the `ngRequest` in service and use it. You can refer the example also

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, can you help me?